# Referencing a pointer to a struct that contains a pointer to a pointer to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, nested

I'm having a hard time referencing the memory inside the struct, I'm not sure that my syntax is correct (although considering other posts I think I'm fine).
The code crashes in Run-time.
As far as I'm aware I've allocated the momory needed (52 cards - line 66) but I'm not sure what casting to apply.
I just need that little push and guidance, thanks alot !

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DECK_SIZE (52)

/* the enum suite definition */
enum suite {
    diamond = 1,
    club,
    heart,
    spade
};

/* the card definition */
struct card {
    int number;
    enum suite type;
};

/* the deck definition */
struct deck {
    struct card ** cards;
    int numCards;
};

/* **
 * Name: addCard(deck *myDeck);
 * Purpose: Add a card to the deck
 ** */
void addCard(struct deck * myDeck)
{
    int number,suiteType;
    printf("Please enter card number: \n");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    printf("Please enter suite type: \n");
    scanf("%d",&suiteType);
    /* increase myDeck->numCards by one */
    myDeck->numCards += 1;
    /* reallocate the block and increase the size by one */
    *(myDeck->cards) = (struct card*) realloc ( *(myDeck->cards), sizeof(struct card) * myDeck->numCards);
    if ( NULL == *(myDeck->cards) ) {
        printf("realloc failed - exiting..\n");
        free( *(myDeck->cards));        
        return;
    }
    /* put the data */
    myDeck->cards[myDeck->numCards-1]->number = number;
    myDeck->cards[myDeck->numCards-1]->type = suiteType;
}

/***
 * Name: initializeDeck();
 * Puspose: create a deck memory block and fill it
 ***/
struct deck * initializeDeck()
 {
    struct deck * myDeck;
    int num,suite,i;
    /* allocate memory for a deck */
    myDeck = (struct deck*) malloc ( sizeof(struct deck) );
    if (NULL == myDeck) {
        printf("Failed to allocate a deck, exiting..\n");
        return 0;
    }
    /* allocte 52 cards */
    myDeck->numCards = DECK_SIZE;
    myDeck->cards = (struct card**) malloc ( sizeof(struct card) * myDeck->numCards );
    if (NULL == *(myDeck->cards)) {
        printf("Failed to allocate 52 cards, exiting..\n");
        free(myDeck);
        return 0;
    }
    /* fill the deck */
    num = 1;
    suite=1;
    for (i = 0; i<DECK_SIZE; i++) {
        myDeck->cards[i]->number = num;
        myDeck->cards[i]->type = suite;
        num++;
        if (num > 13) {
            num = 1;
            suite++;
        }
    }
    return myDeck;
 }

int main()
{
    struct deck * myDeck;
    myDeck = initializeDeck();
    addCard(myDeck);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first glance I see two things (which might not solve the root cause, but actually could help in writing more save code ;-))

1.1 If initialising fails you return NULL, but you do not test the result of `initializeDeck()` but call `addCard` even if `myDeck` is NULL. So in case of an error during initialisation `addCard` causes a crash when dereferencing `myDeck`.

Either do like follows in `main()`:

```
[...]
if (myDeck)
  addCard(myDeck);
[...]
```

or and even better and do like follows in `addCard`:

```
void addCard(struct deck * myDeck)
{
  if (!myDeck) {
    printf("invalid input\n");
    return;
  }
  [...]
```

1.2 `malloc()` returns NULL on failure, so test the result and do not dereference it:

```
[...]
myDeck->cards = (struct card**) malloc ( sizeof(struct card) * myDeck->numCards );
if (NULL == myDeck->cards) {
    printf("Failed to allocate 52 cards, exiting..\n");
[...]
```

Looking closer one realises you are obviously not sure how to arrange your data... ;-)

This line

```
myDeck->cards = (struct card**) malloc ( sizeof(struct card) * myDeck->numCards );
```

should allocate an array of pointers which's entries then in turn for each card should get memory assigend.

So there are two mistakes:

2.1 You assign to much memory to the pointer referencing the array of pointers to cards.

2.2 You are missing to assign the memory for the cards themselfs.

To fix 2.1 do change the line above into:

```
 myDeck->cards = (struct card**) malloc ( sizeof(struct card *) * myDeck->numCards );
```

To fix 2.2 do add the following to the loop assigning the cards' values.

```
  [...]
  for (i = 0; i<DECK_SIZE; i++) {
    myDeck->cards[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct card));
    /* adding error checking here is left as an exercise ... */
    myDeck->cards[i]->number = num;
    [...]
```

Adding those two fixes gets you further ... ;-)

Hint: The same two mistakes you did when allocating the deck (2.1 and 2.2) you do in the code adding a card (`addCard()`).

Btw: Casting the result of `malloc()` seems unnecessary to me, as `malloc()` return `void *` which is compatible to any pointer.

Anyhow type casting in general is not good idea as it keeps the compiler from pointing you to something which might be not the way it should be.

Comment: thank you very much for the in depth explanation ! helped me very much !

Answer (score 0):

You allocate an array containing pointers to cards, but not the cards themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This call allocates a single block of `myDeck->numCards` cards:

```
malloc ( sizeof(struct card) * myDeck->numCards );
```

...but a `struct card **` is not the appropriate variable to hold a pointer to such a block.  You should use just a `struct card *` for this member, and then use `.` rather than `->` to access each member of this array:

```
myDeck->cards[i].number = num;
myDeck->cards[i].type = suite;
```

---

The rule to use is that a `type *` points at a (block of) `type`s.  So a `struct card *` is for pointing at a (block of) `struct card`s, and a `struct card **` points at a (block of) `struct card *`s.

If you want to use a `struct card **` member in your struct, you need to first allocate a block of `struct card *`s for it to point at:

```
myDeck->cards = malloc (sizeof(struct card *) * myDeck->numCards);
if (NULL == myDeck->cards) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %d card pointers, exiting..\n", myDeck->numCards);
```

Now you can allocate the cards themselves, putting the pointers to the cards in the array of pointers allocated earlier.  The simplest way to do this is one allocation per card:

```
for (i = 0; i < myDeck->numCards; i++)
    myDeck->cards[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct card));
```

Your reallocation should then look like:

```
struct card **new_block;

myDeck->numCards += 1;
/* reallocate the block of pointers and increase the size by one */
new_block = realloc (myDeck->cards, sizeof(struct card *) * myDeck->numCards);
if (NULL == new_block) {
    fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed - exiting..\n");
    return;
}
myDeck->cards = new_block;
/* Allocate the new card */
myDeck->cards[myDeck->numCards - 1] = malloc(sizeof(struct card));
if (myDeck->cards[myDeck->numCards - 1] == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate card\n");
    myDeck->numCards--;
    return;
}
/* put the data */
myDeck->cards[myDeck->numCards - 1]->number = number;
myDeck->cards[myDeck->numCards - 1]->type = suiteType;
```

Comment: okay, but lets say that I am "forced" to use a 'struct card **' (hence pointer to pointer). Would you implement it differently from what I implemented above ?

Comment: @shluvme: Yes.  If you use a `struct card **` then you effectively have an array of pointers to cards rather than an array of cards.  This means that you must allocate a block of pointers *and* allocate the cards themselves - I have update my answer to show this.

Comment: thank you very much ! indeed that's what I ended up doing and it did the job :)